# Qt Execute external program

Tags: c++, qt, external

I want to start an external program out of my QT-Programm. The only working solution was:

```
system("start explorer.exe");
```

But it is only working for windows and starts a command line for a moment.

Next thing I tried was:

```
QProcess process;
QString file = QDir::homepath + "file.exe";
process.start(file);
//process.execute(file); //i tried as well
```

But nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: What thomas_b says. Additionally, connect to the finished() and error() signals and call errorString() in case of error to learn about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your `process` object is a variable on the stack (e.g. in a method), the code wouldn't work as expected because the process you've already started will be killed in the destructor of `QProcess`, when the method finishes.

```
void MyClass::myMethod()
{
    QProcess process;
    QString file = QDir::homepath + "file.exe";
    process.start(file);
}
```

You should instead allocate the [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) object on the heap like that:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString file = QDir::homepath + "/file.exe";
process->start(file);
```

Comment: Will the QProcess automatically deallocate itself, when the process has started?

Comment: No, it won't. If the `process` object is getting deleted, it kills the corresponding process. With the static method `QProcess::startDetached` it is possible to start a new process without carrying a `QProcess` instance around.

Comment: Is there another approach starting a process? I just want to fire a process and forget about it.

Comment: Yes, with the mentioned static method `QProcess:startDetached`

Comment: Oh this is really hidden, i've asked this question couple of minutes ago, maybe you can send your answer there, then it is available for all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670147/qt-start-external-process-fire-and-forget

Answer (score 8):

If you want your program to wait while the process is executing and only  need to get its exit code, you can use

```
QProcess::execute(file);
QProcess::exitCode(); // returns the exit code
```

instead of using process asynchronously like this.

```
QProcess process;
process.start(file);
```

Note that you can also block execution until process will be finished. In order to do that use

```
process.waitForFinished();
```

after start of the process.

Comment: This is an option worth considering. [Execute](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute-1) is a convenience function that executes a process and waits for it to finish. It's static though. You don't call it on a `QProcess` instance.

Answer (score 5):

QDir::homePath doesn't end with separator. Valid path to your exe

```
QString file = QDir::homePath + QDir::separator + "file.exe";
```

Comment: On qt5.11 I had to use `homePath()` and `separator()`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`QProcess::startDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-2); it's static and you don't need to worry about waiting for it to finish or allocating things on the heap or anything like that:

```
QProcess::startDetached(QDir::homepath + "/file.exe");
```

It's the detached counterpart to `QProcess::execute`.

As of 5.15 that form is obsolete (but still present). The new preferred call is the same as the above but with a `QStringList` of command line arguments as the second parameter. If you don't have any arguments to pass just pass an empty list.

Comment: It's deprecated since 5.15. Use `QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments)` instead

Comment: @Dmytro confirmed in 5.15 docs and updated as best as I could from my phone. thanks!!