# QT Start External Process (Fire and Forget)

Tags: c++, qt

How can i start an external Process in QT 5 without caring about what is happening with the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Execute external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442400/qt-execute-external-program)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible with the static method [`QProcess::startDetached`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached).