# Qt display an image without showing console on a VS2010 windows subsystem

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt 4.7.1, I'm trying to start the Windows Photo Viewer when I click on a button.

Here is a demo project I've set up in VS2010:

```
// Container.h
#pragma once

#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>

#include <cstdlib>
class Container : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QPushButton* m_button;

    Container(){
        m_button = new QPushButton("Open Image");
        bool status = connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked()));
    }

    public slots:
    void onButtonClicked(){

        // works, with console popup:
         system(<path to image>);

        // doesn't work:
        // QProcess::execute(<path to png>);
    }

};
```

and the main file:

```
// Main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Container.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 QApplication app(argc, argv);

 Container c;

 c.m_button->show();

return app.exec();
}
```

My subsystem is set to Windows, for I do not wish a background console: 
[image]

Now the problem. I would like to display the image without displaying a console window. Calling system() briefly opens a console, closes it and then shows the image. an example call is as follows:

```
system("G:\\image.png");
```

So how can I show the image without this console? 
Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: It has been pointed out this post may be a duplicate of :
[Qt Execute external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442400/qt-execute-external-program)

Sorry, I've tried the solution explained there but could not get it running. In my particular case, I think the Subsystem plays a role.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Execute external program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442400/qt-execute-external-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **QDesktopServices** with something like

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(localFilePath));
```

The `openUrl()` function can be customized to implement your own dispatch mechanism (does not apply in your case - i think).

Comment: that did it! Thank you!