# Executing a MSI file from a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, windows-installer

I have written a Qt application that downloads and then executes an MSI file. The execution is done via `QProcess` and is using the information provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442400/qt-execute-external-program).

Whenever I run it using `QProcess` an exception is thrown:

> Exception thrown: read access violation

which seems to be a rights management problem. However I don't know where the problem is exactly and how to fix it. Here is an example code snippet:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString program = "file.msi";
QString folder = "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\";
process->start(program, QStringList() << folder);
```

Comment: Show a brief example of the code you are using for this. We can't solve bugs in code we can't see.

Comment: I've given a link and its exactly as shown.

Comment: There should not this issue using QProcess. You likely have a bug in your code or a dll conflict. We can not help with either if we can not reproduce. I can assure you that I use QProcess in several of my applications and none of them do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that an MSI file is an installation file thus it requires administrator privileges.

There are two options:

- try using `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///<path to your MSI file>"), QUrl::TolerantMode));` (as suggested [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/18570/windows-7-launch-aplication-with-admin-rights/3)) instead of using `QProcess`.
- Use the Windows `runas` by calling `QProcess::startDetached("runas /user:<localmachinename>\user msiFileName");` where you replace the respective strings with your own (for that you should check the [documentation of `runas`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx) since this has nothing to do with Qt but with the command line arguments of `runas`.

In addition you can run your Qt application with administrator privileges. In order to save the user the rouble of doing it manually you can use [this](https://signalslot.com/how-to-enable-qt-applications-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-bca13d6c28dc) to tell Windows what the default execution of your Qt application is supposed to be. This is something I would advise against because your application may introduce a security breach in the system that you can be held liable for.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem.